# How to get Codeigniter 3 to use project root instead of referencing full file path on localhost for key folders

Tags: codeigniter-3

I've looked around and I'm sure this is common but can't seem to get the right answer.

I've just recently set up a Codeigniter 3 project on my localhost and a migrating some Codeigniter 2 code.

The index.php file is a bit different.

I can get the project up and running except the main folders references in the index.php file such as APPLICATION and others I've added like "ASSETS" etc are loading like this:

```
 <link href="http://[::1]/projectOne/E:\public_html\projectOne\assets\css\style.php?1537317115" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Even when I set a base_url:

```
  <link href="http://localhost/projectOne/E:\public_html\projectOne\assets\css\style.php?1537317115" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

I've checked it wasn't just the folders I added by echoing out the APPPATH variable:

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
echo APPPATH;
```

Which produces:

```
E:\public_html\projectOne\application\
```

What am I missing here?

How do I get my paths to folder set in the index.php to just use the project root, and not the whole filepath on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone else that hits this issue.

This new part in CI3:

```
if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $application_folder = $_temp;
    }
```

Allows you to more securely/easily have your application folder outside of the website root.

My additional ASSETS folder was then showing the full web path which you obviously don't want.

So commenting out this part leaving only:

```
$application_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
```

And then setting you base_url value in the config.php file gives your CSS, JS and IMAGES proper site relative paths.